# Бан аккаунта разработчика Google chrome

Tags: google-chrome, chrome-extension

Недавно сделал для себя расширение для хрома и решил его выложить в магазин. Расширение не сложное, обычный генератор паролей на js, вставка паролей в поля + добавление некоторых кнопок на страницу. Никаких ajax запросов нет.

Через некоторое время после добавления расширение удалили с магазина и прислали письмо на почту, что в расширении есть какой-то скрытый код (при добавлении расширения разработчик отправляет архив с файлами с кодом). Что такое скрытый код и где они его нашли, я так и не понял...

Добавил расширение ещё раз ничего не изменяя, через некоторое время его подтвердили. 2 недели расширение висело в магазине, установили его всего 3 человека. Сегодня прислали письмо, что аккаунт разработчика забанен. Ни объяснений, ни причин... Просто забанен.

Из-за чего гугл может просто так банить?
Если нужно, само расширение могу выложить сюда

UPD: https://github.com/Devvvvv/gh

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что ответ на данный вопрос знает только компания Google.

Comment: Попробуйте искать ответ на форумах разработчиков Google. [Похожий вопрос там](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-extensions/HljKaTs9ax8)

Comment: @kff, может быть у кого-то были подобные случаи или кто-нибудь знает, что не любит гугл. Зачем же сразу закрывать, если только Вам этот вопрос неинтересен?

Comment: @Dev Кто закрыл? Вопрос открыт. Это только моё мнение. Оно может быть и не поддержано сообществом. Закроют только после пяти голосов. А вообще Google может банить и просто так, случаи известны. Что им не понравилось в Вашем конкретном случае, знают только они.

Comment: Это оффтопик. Здесь обсуждаются вопросы, как правильно программировать, а не причины бана у Гугла.

Comment: @VladD возможно, это вопрос «как правильно программировать, чтобы код проходил проверки у Google» – по-моему, вполне валидный вопрос.

Comment: @Sergiks: Ну, так можно обобщить до «как правильно запрограммировать операционную систему, чтобы была лучше линукса» или там «как правильно сделать лабу, текст задания прилагается».

Comment: @Sergiks: Если даже считать вопрос онтопиком  — где код? На основании чего мы должны ответить? Аналогичный вопрос по программированию был бы «Я написал программу, а она чёта вылетает, где может быть ошибка?».

Comment: @VladD нет, обобщение преувеличено. Если мы в ответе докопаемся до верной детали, напр., что не стоит прилагать минифицированные библиотеки – это поможет и другим разработчикам расширений Chrome. Хотите ли вы, чтобы ответ нашёлся на SO или в специализированных форумах google developers?

Comment: @Dev выложите код расширения, или ссылку на репо.

Comment: @Sergiks https://github.com/Devvvvv/gh

Answer (score 5):

Вероятно, вы нарушили [Program Policies](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/program_policies) или [Developer Agreement](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/terms).

Можно попробовать [восстановить свои права](http://support.google.com/chrome_webstore/contact/cws_dev_appeals), если уверены что забанили ни за что.

Предполагаю, пальцем в небо, что *забанили* за повторную отправку неисправленного кода.

Был ли в расширении обфусцированный / нечитаемый код? (что они назвали «скрытый код») Это могло вызвать подозрения в похищении паролей.  В секции [Content Policies](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/program_policies#content_policies) см. последние два предолжения:

> Malicious Products:
>      Don't transmit viruses, worms, defects, Trojan horses, malware, or any other items of a destructive nature. We don't allow content that harms or interferes with the operation of the networks, servers, or other infrastructure of Google or any third-parties. Spyware, malicious scripts, and password phishing scams are also prohibited in the Chrome Web Store.
>
> Where possible, make as much of your code visible in the package as you can. If some of your app's logic is hidden and it appears to be suspicious, we may remove it.

Comment: Спасио за ответ. Есть файл jquery.min.js, полностью скопированный с официального сайта. Он весь в 4 строки, вроде нечитаемый...

Comment: Теоретически злодей мог и среди кода jQuery разместить свои закладки. Может, стоило неминифицированную версию библиотеки привести, или брать jQuery с Google CDN? Точно не знаю, только предполагаю.